# La parola “smarmellare”

Tags: word-usage

Nella serie televisiva [*Boris*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_(serie_televisiva)) (2007-2010) viene usato più volte il termine “smarmellare”, detto delle luci sul set: dal contesto si capisce che si riferisce all'uso di luci forti che illuminano uniformemente la scena, essenzialmente per evitare lo sforzo di creare giochi di luce più elaborati.

Non trovo questo termine su nessun dizionario, né su Google Ngram, e anche le occorrenze in rete precedenti al 2007 sono pressoché nulle, almeno con questo significato.

Mi sapete dire – fonti alla mano – se è un termine tecnico usato effettivamente in ambito cinematografico e televisivo, o se è un'invenzione degli autori della serie (cosa possibilissima dato il tono generale di *Boris*)?

Comment: Il termine sembra essere in uso sui social network: " ***Smarmellare***, per chi si occupa di social media management, significa condividere in modo positivo, condividere e coinvolgere le persone con contenuti che ti interessano e che potrebbero interessare il tuo pubblico." Gli autori di Boris potrebbero avere mutuato il termine dalla rete. L'idea di "spalmare" uniformemente le luci come le informazioni  è affine. http://vmktg.blogspot.it/2014/10/dai-smarmella-un-po-anche-me.html?m=1

Comment: Grazie, @xxxxxx, non lo sapevo! Bisognerebbe capire se viceversa non sia stato *Boris* (che fu trasmesso dal 2007 al 2010) a diffondere o addirittura creare il termine che poi sarebbe stato ripreso da altri.

Comment: Unica "fonte": "Per restare nelle tematiche della scuola anchei termini gergali che siriferiscono all'interrogazione o alla ... sui due opposti versanti, da una parte ***chi sta ammosciato, accasciato, smarmellato,***   spiaccicato.".. https://books.google.it/books?id=XuFZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT368&lpg=PT368&dq=smarmellare+o+spalmare&source=bl&ots=oOnrCQgm-H&sig=eyNfDEsYj5nYIUVmhw1lprq_U2w&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK2JDD34fPAhVcFMAKHbZrCAwQ6AEIJjAD#v=onepage&q=smarmellare%20o%20spalmare&f=false

Comment: Fonte "esperienza personale": in provincia di Siracusa, ben prima di Boris, ho sentito usare il termine "fare marmellata", "smarmellare" per indicare "esagerare" e, di riflesso, "vivere in maniera ostentata".

Comment: @DaG, nel link https://books.google.de/books?id=sVU7DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT14&dq=smarmellare&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=smarmellare&f=false viene inteso come "distribuire". A primo udito avrei pensato al verbo "diffondere", verbo che nel caso di luci si adatta anche bene, che si riferisca solo a queste non saprei con precisione, come non sono sicuro sul "variante: “Apri tutto!”" che leggo qui anche https://books.google.de/books?id=hu0PCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT21&dq=smarmella&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=smarmella&f=false

Comment: Inoltre qui https://books.google.de/books?id=PwXaAAAAMAAJ&q=smarmellare&dq=smarmellare&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y e qui https://books.google.de/books?id=Y0MEAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&dq=smarmella&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=smarmella&f=false leggo un uso insolito anche se riesco a capirlo...

Comment: Grazie mille per le segnalazioni, @mle. Andando con ordine: la prima (https://books.google.de/books?id=sVU7DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT14&dq=smarmellare&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=smarmellare&f=false) è effettivamente molto affine a “diffondere”, detto dell'uso sui social media, come vedi anche nel primo commento di Gio qui sopra; [segue]

Comment: il secondo (https://books.google.de/books?id=hu0PCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT21&dq=smarmella&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=smarmella&f=false) è accostato a “Apri tutto!” per il il senso, ma soprattutto perché sono entrambe battute dello stesso personaggio di *Boris*, che è interpretato da Ninni Bruschetta, l'autore di qul libro; nel terzo (https://books.google.de/books?id=PwXaAAAAMAAJ&q=smarmellare&dq=smarmellare&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y) “smarmellare” ha un senso un po' diverso: maciullare, spiaccicare, ridurre a marmellata (quello che può succedere a un bambino se si spara a chi lo tiene in braccio);

Comment: nel quarto (https://books.google.de/books?id=Y0MEAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&dq=smarmella&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=smarmella&f=false) infine, l'uso sembra un po' insolito, ma se vedi è un autore (che non conosco) che sembra usare le parole in modo molto creativo, fra virgolette, attribuendo significati scherzosi etc. Direi che voglia dire qualcosa come “sparare, scodellare”, detto di una frase a effetto.

Comment: @DaG, pardone se rispondo in ritardo, alle volte le notifiche nell´app non arrivano per tutti i post ove ho commentato e vi commentano (devo aprire le questioni e vedere personalmente). Sul termine **maciullare** come **ridurre a marmellata** hai saputo perfettamente dare un senso che a me sfuggiva pur capendo il testo. Per il quarto adesso è piú chiaro anche qui.. grazie!

Comment: Difficile dire se sia venuto prima l’uso satirico di _Boris_ o l’uso gergale (non necessariamente cinematografico) che si trova in Rete. Certo è che si tratta di una retroformazione scherzosa da _marmellata_ (come se _marmellata_ fosse un participio passato) che si presta assai bene all’uso in un contesto comico come quello di Boris. Forse ricordo male, ma mi pare che nella serie lo stesso Duccio Patanè spieghi — forse a uno stagista — il significato della parola…

Comment: Uso questo termine dai primi del 2000, per il gruppo di persone con cui lo utilizzavo ha sempre significato "spalmarsi da qualche parte a rilassarsi".

Comment: Smarmellare quando si parla di luci vuol dire in un certo senso bruciare. In pratica esagerare con la luce porta a bruciare l’immagine che, in gergo, ne esce smarmellata

Comment: personalmente ho sempre immaginato che facessero riferimento proprio alla marmellata e all'idea di usare la luce come può essere data la marmellata "a cazzo di cane" (altro leit-motiv) smarmellando sul pane. Sembra un mio trip stupido e forse lo è, ma la mia logica era che siccome i filtri delle luci da set si chiamano gelatine loro avessero ironizzato su termini affini.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Secondo Francesca La Forgia e Raffaella Tonin, ricercatrici e poi docenti all'Università di Bologna nel dipartimento di Studi Linguistici, si tratterebbe di un termine (almeno nel contesto cinematografico) inventato all'interno della serie. Nel loro *[articolo](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=2ahUKEwjz9drPnsPhAhUFIVAKHSwZDgMQFjAIegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.academia.edu%2F27073001%2FIl_parlato_delle_serie_televisive_il_caso_di_Cu%25C3%25A9ntame_e_di_Boris&usg=AOvVaw0_quqjyxz9UEnxXxeW8pJz)* "Il parlato delle serie televisive: il caso di *Cuéntame* e di *Boris*" del 2016, a pagina 16, sezione 3.1.(La lingua di *Boris*) si legge

> Il lessico [della serie] attinge a vari registri, e sono presenti anche forestierismi e tecnicismi
> legati prevalentemente all’ambito televisivo e cinematografico come “steady-cam”,
> “combo”, “fegatelli”, ma soprattutto **il neologismo**, già visto precedentemente [nell'articolo] e usato
> come pseudo tecnicismo, “smarmellare” che è diventato subito un tormentone
> linguistico (S03E13, 12’12’’):

Comment: Ottima segnalazione, grazie mille!

Answer (score 3):

Da *Andy Warhol era un coatto* (1994) di Tommaso Labranca:

> E mentre suggevo il finnico banano di Hans, il compare mi smarmellava il rigoglioso tettame.

Comment: La risposta è un po' laconica (mi sono permesso di aggiungere almeno il nome del buon Labranca), ma il reperto è ottimo!

Comment: Grazie... mi sono addirittura iscritto per risponderti... ma non ho resistito! Comunque conta il 1994, per dedurre che la parola, con l'accezione di "spalmare" risale ad epoca pre-Boris. Ora bisognerebbe scrivere agli sceneggiatori!

Answer (score 0):

In Italia succede spesso che serie televisive e trasmissioni, soprattutto comico-satiriche "lancino" nuove parole o anche le trasformino usandolo in contesti diversi che poi fanno presa soprattutto fra i giovani e il loro gergo. In questo caso smarmellare significa chiaramente spalmare ma riferito alle luci di scena anziché alla marmellata sul pane (che comunque sarebbe stato un verbo inventato) e per quanto difficile da dimostrare azzarderei inventato dagli sceneggiatori di Boris.

Comment: Grazie, @tent, ma questo è appunto l'azzardo che avevo formulato io, quasi un anno fa, ponendo la domanda. Cercavo, come dico nella domanda, fonti precise, o di un uso preesistente in questo preciso ambito, o di un'origine dovuta specificamente agli sceneggiatori di *Boris*.